# Push ID emaila to empty array. Google Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, mapping, push

I push the ID of unread emails to the 'emailIdArr' table.
Each next push creates a new, one element larger array.
I want to get just one array with all ids.
I need help. I don't know how to solve my problem.
**Thank you!**

```js
function pushID()  {
const threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();

      const emailIdArr = [];
      
      threads.forEach((message)=>{      
      if(message.isUnread() === true){

        emailIdArr.push(message.getId())
        Logger.log(emailIdArr)
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: emailIdArr does contain all ids. What are you looking for?

Comment: Shouldn't you log the array at the end, after processing all message threads? `Logger.log` should be outside the arrow function you are passing to `threads.forEach`. From you requirements, you already solved the problem: `emailAddr` is an `array` with all the message IDs. Not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: Yes! Logger.log should be outside the arrow function. Thanks very much!